# Binded objects in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, components, 2-way-object-databinding

I have the following code:

```
class TreeComponent {

    entity: any;

    constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IScope) {
        console.log(this.entity);         
    }
}


AppModule.component('tree', {

    templateUrl: '<tree entity="obj"></tree>',
    controller: ['$rootScope', TreeComponent],
    bindings: {
        entity: '='
    }

})
```

I expect that console.log(this.entity) prints the obj inserted to 'tree' tag. I don't know why but it prints 'undefined'. Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out that 'entity' attribute is binded to the object only after leaving the constructor. For example,

```
class TreeComponent {

    entity: any;

    constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IScope) {
        console.log(this.entity);         
    }
    debug() {
        console.log(this.entity);// it works
    }

}
```